# ionic2 Views do not update, code does execute

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've updated my projects and dependancies a little bit.
Whenever I render a page for the first time, (Except root) it doesn't work straight away.

F/e I have a root page, which is a login form. Whenever a token is present in the localStorage, this will be provided by an emitter to the login page. Then the injected NavController, pushes my main Page, a TabController.

This doesn't happen straight away, I can pick my nose, go to the bathroom it stays on the root Page. It only pushes the new view when I actually focus my input. (It also shows a bit of black when it can't render a page and ionic crashes when you do something wrong.

Then on the tabs page, The first tab does not render, it does however when I click the first tab, same for other tabs, they need to be clicked twice (the tab bar only becomes active when you click twice as well). After this it's all working fine, but surely, not what we want.
Here is a video of what I'm seeing. If you pause the video at 0.0 you see the logs state Token successfull. This is as in code, right before the push. The new page is initiated, the views just don't seem to be updated until I click an element like the input.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.subscribe(token => {
        if (token && token.length) {
            console.log("token returned success!", token, this.navController);
            setTimeout( () => { this.navController.push(<any>MainTabs); }, 250 );
        } else {
            console.log("token returned", token);
        }
    });
}
```

Errors in log are angular2 & ionic in browser related.

So as you see, when the Push is triggered which doesn't ;look as it should, the first page keeps showing a loader. This should go away once content is loaded (it is loaded I saw the console.logs trigger which set the value). If I'd click the first tab item 2 times now it'd show the content. 
I chose to click the "Acties" button, which rendered the first tab (note I was clicking the third). Clicking the fourth renders the third page, after this, they have been rendered once and clicks work as expected.

Wierd?

Comment: I don't have access to the video (access denied)... What does the `sessionService` do?

Comment: Ah shucks video expired.

It's not important what the sessionService does, however it stores things like tokens etc. in localStorage. on starting the app it checks the storage and emits this to subscribers. (the token). So they can handle it and assume it's in-session. Once it's invalidated it will clear the token and emit this etc.

Comment: This let me think about problem with zones. Do you try to execute the subscribed callback within a zone with the `NgZone` class? See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html

Comment: I've never used NgZone, I use EventEmitter from Angular2/core.

Note that it also happens when I'm not doing anything with eventEmitter, I'm uploading a gif now

Comment: I've updated with a screenie gif of my troubles.

Comment: I think we need more code than this. What exactly is `MainTabs`? Anyways, I've come across some weird issues as well with `angular2` where i had to do something twice for it to update the view. What worked for me as a **disgusting** fix was to add `this._application.tick();`, where `application` is a `ApplicationRef` injected in the `constructor`. You can try to put that after you click on a tab. With perhaps a `setTimeout` around it..

Comment: MainTabs itself is a Page, with the 4 tabs, so <ionic-tabs> with 4 tabs refering a page, all pretty standard tbh.

Comment: I do believe it is probably due to dependancies, but no  errors etc. make me sad.

Comment: I do wonder though if it "works" if you use the `application.tick()` with a 200ms `setTimeout`. It is a dirty work around, maar het is maar de kruidvat ;). I've already encountered this problem twice, and i suspect this is a problem within `angular2`.. But I can't determine where it comes from

Comment: I'd like to try, do you have any docs/example on how to implement application.tick?

Yes I wanted to hide the branding stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to add a dirty fix with `tick()`

```
@App({
  template: `
    <ion-tabs (change)="_onTabChange()">
      <ion-tab tabIcon="heart" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="star" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>`
})
class MyApp {
  constructor(private _applicationRef : ApplicationRef) {
    this.tab1 = Tab1;
    this.tab2 = Tab2;
  }

  private _onTabChange() : void {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this._applicationRef.tick();
     }, 200);
  }
}
```

**Apparently the none dirty trick is to remove ionic's polyfills**

Comment: That change does not seem to work btw, but calling tick is fine, I could put it in all constructors or w/e.

Comment: Just found out it's worse, after any API request, it doesn't update the view, so I'd have to do a tick every time a response was received. f. yeah

Comment: @MathijsSegers That almost sounds like that in the `ionic.bundle.js` they didn't add `angular-polyfills.js`...

Comment: I'll look into that comment. I do have some custom config going on so it is probably my issue. Could you explain what part would be missing in that case or is it an assumption?

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know why, but because I"m including multiple polyfills it broke. It's working now after removing ionic's.

Comment: It was just an assumption. Problems where the app would not update after an async request, is usually caused by the absence of the `angular-polyfills` :) but glad i could help.

Comment: Yes thanks again, It was included double I guess maybe ionic's was too old since myself I use beta 9.

Comment: Works in `2.0.0-rc.2` too!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the permanent solution I'm quite certain;
However as stated in @PiereDuc 's comments it can be resolved by enforcing application.tick

so in your Main App component (is it a component?). You inject the ApplicationRef, then you can do something like.

```
  setInterval(() => { app.tick(); }, 400);
```

This, is disgusting but it works for now. I'll update this when I know what's going on.

Comment: Works great. Going to use this in `2.0.0-rc.2`. Had this problem of views not updated when using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` event. This solves it for now.

Comment: Try to find out if something is wrong, because you're not supposed to need this. My problem was double / unnecessary polyfills

Comment: My demo app is just the bare tabs template created by ionic cli. I see in the console that my page variable is changed but not reflected in the view. Also have this when using `this.events.publish` and `this.events.subscribe` I see the event fired and a variable set but view is not updated.